# Binding to viewmodel via a context?

Tags: polymer

I am looking at using Polymer for a new project I am working on. I'm lucky enough to be able to target the latest version of Chrome only.

One of the reasons I am looking at Polymer is that I understand that is uses the new `Object.observe` for data-binding. (I think I am right in saying that, please correct me if I am not!)

One thing I would like to achieve is to be able to run my tests against my view models rather than using  a gui testing tool.

...but as far as I can see, Polymer is setup for the web components to actually be the view models. Am I right in saying that? Now I've not looked into Polymer testing, but I expect that would mean having to have a DOM to test...

Now, I can add a "context" attribute to every web component and bind the JS view model to that and have all the bindings as `{{context.prop}}`, `{{context.prop1}}`, etc...

Is this going against any polymer principle - have I got completely the wrong idea?

**Example element:**

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="context">
    <template>
        <textarea value="{{context.prop}}"></textarea>
    </template>
    <script>Polymer({});</script>
</polymer-element>
```

**Element use:**

```
<my-element id="ele"></my-element>
<script>
    var model = { prop: 'initial value' }

    // wait for DOM to load - should really use some sort of "ready" event here...
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            var ele = document.querySelector('#ele');
            ele.context = model;
        }, 3000);

    Object.observe(model, function() { console.log('changed'); });
</script>
```